# getResourceAsStream() Not Finding Resource in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classloader, getresource

I'm having trouble loading an image resource in a Maven-based Java project. The file seems to be correctly placed in the src/main/resources directory, but I keep getting an error that the image is not found. I am new to working with files and images. I'm working on a little program that takes an image and outputs it as ASCII art. I had it working for a while, and then it stopped working.

`Image not found in resources: cat.png`

File Tree:

```
ImageConverter
└───src
    ├───main
    │   ├───java
    │   │   └───(my packages)
    │   └───resources
    │       └───cat.png
    └───test
```

Relevant Image class code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URL;


public class Image {
    // Reference https://paulbourke.net/dataformats/asciiart/
    private static final String DEFAULTIMAGE = "cat.png";
    private static final String ASCIICHARS = ".'`^\\\",:;Il!i><~+_-?][}{1)(|\\\\/tfjrxnuvczXYUJCLQ0OZmwqpdbkhao*#MW&8%B@$"; // taken from https://medium.com/@shubham0473/unleash-your-inner-artist-a-step-by-step-guide-to-converting-images-to-ascii-art-using-java-97860464f19a
    private static final double MAX_LUMINANCE = 196964.0;
    private BufferedImage img;


    public Image(){
        this(DEFAULTIMAGE);
    }

    public Image(String filename) {
        try {

            URL input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename);
            //InputStream input = Image.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
            System.out.println(input);
            if (input==null) {
                System.err.println("Image not found in resources: " + filename);
                return;
            }
            this.img = ImageIO.read(input);
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Error loading image: " + filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getImg(){
        return this.img;
    }

    public String toString(){
        // use convertToASCII to create the string to be printed to the console.
        char[][] ASCIItable = convertToASCII(this.img);
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (char[] table : ASCIItable){
            for (char cell : table){
                s.append(cell);
            }
            s.append("\n");
        }
        return s.toString();
    }


    public char[][] convertToASCII(BufferedImage img){
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance
        FastRGB pixels = new FastRGB(img);
        char[][] ASCII_array = new char[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];

        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++){
                short[] currentPixel = pixels.getRGB(x, y);
                double r = currentPixel[0];
                double g = currentPixel[1];
                double b = currentPixel[2];

                double rr = Math.pow(r, 2.2);
                double gg = Math.pow(g, 2.2);
                double bb = Math.pow(b, 2.2);

                double luminance = rr * 0.2126 + gg * 0.7152 + bb * 0.0722;
                char luminanceChar = luminanceToASCII(luminance);
                ASCII_array[x][y] = luminanceChar;
            }
        }
        return ASCII_array;
    }

    public char luminanceToASCII(double n){
        n = ((n / MAX_LUMINANCE) * ASCIICHARS.length()) - 1;
        if (n < 0)
            n = 0;
        return ASCIICHARS.charAt((int)n);
    }
}
```

Printing the URL input prints null.
I have tried the following:

- Confirming that `cat.png` is directly inside the `resources` folder.
- Ensuring `src/main/resources` is marked as a resource root in the IDE.
- Using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename)` instead.
- Using an InputStream and File object.
- 3 different images inside the same folder.
- Attempting to load the image using an absolute path on the filesystem.

I really wish I didn't get careless and used git so I could at least revert to a working state...
Suggestions? I hope I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` will try to find the resource in the same folder structure as classes are searched for, that is, the folders on the CLASSPATH - check if `cat.png` (and other content of `resources`) was copied to the same folder where the `.class` files are or the package folder of these classes ((if you use `getClass().getResource("cat.png")` the file will be searched in the same folder as the `.class` file, kind of same package as the class))

Comment: Yeah there's no images in there... Ill have to figure out how to get them in there. Or can i just copy them over?

Comment: I would use `private static final String DEFAULTIMAGE = "/cat.png";` instead

Comment: usually it is the IDE that copy the file, but I do not use IDEA - you can copy it, but not sure how that will work with IDEA (some IDEs clear the destination folder before (re-) compiling) - and Maven also has a *role*  in that

Comment: @MadProgrammer if using the `ClassLoader` as posted in question's code, there is no need for the `/`; actually it will not work if using it. Otherwise, if using the class like in `getClass().getResource(...)` then using `/` makes the path absolute, instead of relative to the package of the class (modified_package_name as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)))

Comment: @user85421 The class’s package loading the resource is undefined within the current context. Since the resource exists at the root, defining the absolute path helps solve part of issue you were attempting to explain your previous comment

Comment: @Mad try it, if using the `getClassLoader.getResource()` it will not work if the path starts with a `/`, the argument will already be interpreted as absolute - On the other *side*, hypothetically - not the posted code - if using `getClass.getResource()` the (modified) package of that class is used (unless the given path starts with `/`), in this case the `/` would be needed, but that method is not being used in posted code

Comment: Sorry, on mobile, I’d use `URL input = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename);` in addition to the my first comment

Comment: see https://ideone.com/n85jpy (unfortunately it does not allow package, nor uploading images, so I had to use the class file itself) clearly an argument starting with a `/` does not work when using the ClassLoader's method

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make sure the resources get compiled along the class files? I have it marked as resource root, anything else I can change?

Comment: This has *nothing to do with* `ImageIO` *whatsoever.* It was `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filename)` that failed. Accuracy and precision please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I fixed it! I remade the project in intellij using the intellij project structure, copied over all my class files, made a resources folder, marked as resources route, and now it works. The folder structure looks as follows:

```
ImageConverter2
├───.idea
├───out
│   └───production
│       └───ImageConverter2
├───resources
└───src
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a basic test with the following structure

[image]

(Maven is suppose to be IDE agnostic, so the actually IDE should be irrelevant)

I then used...

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/mandalorian.jpg"));
```

and...

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/mandalorian.jpg"));
```

And both worked.

As a personal preference, I prefer the first, as I can switch between relative and absolute paths as I wish.

In your case I would consider:

- Checking the resulting `.jar` file and making sure that the image(s) are included
- Cleaning and rebuilding the Maven project (ie `mvn clean install` or what ever your IDE provides you to essentially do the same)